# How to convert Image into Byte Array in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am facing one real issue. I need to convert image into **byte array** format, so that I can upload the byte array into web server. I have tried a lot however its not working. I am also getting negative values for byte array. I am not sure what i am doing wrong to take byte values in array.

Below is my code. Please help me what i am doing wrong?

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home_menu_icon);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: [Base64String](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16744086/2332217)

Comment: Don't convert to base64 ... If you care about quality try to compress to PNG format as JPEG is the worst possible: `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);` Otherwise the code code seems to be OK.

Comment: `The fact that primitives are signed in Java is irrelevant - A byte is merely 8 bits and whether you interpret that as a signed range or not is up to you. There is no magic flag to say "this is signed" or "this is unsigned".`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191871/converting-bitmap-to-bytearray-android check this here

Comment: isn't your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Here i show code for both if your image is from GALLERY and CAMERA

```
if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        fileName = getRealPathFromURI(data.getData());

        try {
             if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //picNameText.setText("Selected: en"
                //  + getStringNameFromRealPath(fileName));

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream1);
            imageInByte = stream1.toByteArray();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_TAKER_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        image.setImageBitmap(photo);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream2);
        imageInByte = stream2.toByteArray();

    }
```

enjoy it work for me.....

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
//Create a new buffer
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
//Move the byte data to the buffer
b.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); 
byte[] array = buffer.array();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A 32-bit Bitmap use a int32 to save a ARGB color, and we can use a
   int array to represent a bitmap. Using `Bitmap.getPixels()` and
   `Bitmap.setPixels()` to convert a Bitmap to int array and vise
   verse. And a int array can be easily convert to byte array.
2. @Chintan Rathod also show a good solution by using `Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer()`, nearly       the same with the first one.
3. Since your goal is to upload the bitmap to server, send a compressed
   file is the best solution. Your code is just doing the right thing.
   You said that you are getting negative values in byte array, which
   is not an error. Just upload the byte array to server and save it as
   a jpeg file.

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit Bitmap use a int32 to save a ARGB color, and we can use a int array to represent a bitmap. Using Bitmap.getPixels() and Bitmap.setPixels() to convert a Bitmap to int array and vise verse. And a int array can be easily convert to byte array.