# Store Picture in Preference Acitivity - Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

So I have a Preference Acitivity. What I want to do now is that the user opens the Preferences and can choose a picture from the Gallery. This Picture should then be displayed in the Main Activity

---

I have no idea how to do that, so I hope some of you guys could help me out ;)

Comment: Store the byte representation of the Bitmap into the SharedPrefs?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to tell me :P

Comment: Once you are able to get the picture from the Gallery, I assume it will be a Bitmap object. Then you can just store that as a String or byte array maybe. I'm just throwing ideas out there - but if you don't know how to get a picture from the gallery, you should've asked that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be easily solved by storing the `Byte array` of the Image in one of the Tags of `SharedPreference`. To do this you need to convert the Image which is in a `Bitmap` format to Byte Array. This array can be stored as a text (or `Blob`) format in SharedPreference or `SQLite` Database.

When, you need to display the image in any Activity, retrieve the `Byte Array` and convert it to `Bitmap` again. This Bitmap can be dynamically assigned to the `ImageView` of the Activity.

Refer to this answer for the conversion code: [How to convert Image into Byte Array in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613228/how-to-convert-image-into-byte-array-in-android)